# Why does an attribute has a method?

Tags: python, pytorch

I use pytorch define a Variable x, compute and get its gradient x.grad, meaning grad is an attribute of instance x. But, I can use x.grad.data.zero_() to set x.grad to zero meaning that data.zero_() is method of x.grad. Why does an attribute has a method? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be just an object attribute, for example we can have an attribute of type String. And we all now String have his own methods including the method that prints out the value of itself

Comment: Thank you for your nice answers.  If x.grad is an object attribute, why can I get the value of x.grad via typing x.grad directly instead of x.grad.data? (I find that the value of x.grad is equal to the value of x.grad.data)

Comment: Is just what I said objects defined by a language may implement a function to return a value. Then if you call the object on a context that you need the value stored insde that object the object itself will call the function. For example in C++ you can create a class and override cout method in order to obtain his value. If you don't override the method you will get the value of the pointer.

Comment: Thank you for your patient answers. I set up another example to show my understanding of what you said. For example. I define an array by x = np.array([1,2]), where x can be regarded as an instance of class array initialized with [1,2]. If I want to get [1,2],  I should have typed x.something. But, since there exists a link between object name x and x.something, I just need to type x to get the value [1,2]? My understanding is right?

Comment: Yes, If you print that array or you want to use it on any other operation just giving x you will obtain [1,2].

Comment: Thank you very much. My curiosity is strong. How is this link realized via coding in python? Hope this does not upsetting you.

Comment: I don't know how it works on python but in other languages as C++ or Java this link is made by the compiler itself or the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Because attribute `x.grad` is an object, and in most dynamic languages mostly everything is an object.

Comment: Thank you for your nice answers.  If x.grad is an object attribute, why can I get the value of x.grad via typing x.grad directly instead of x.grad.data? (I find that the value of x.grad is equal to the value of x.grad.data)

Comment: By getting value you mean when you print it, right? If that's the case, when you print an object, its `__str__` or `__repr__` method is called, and that method is likely printing the data.

Comment: Thank you. By getting value, I mean calling it to calculate. For example, x.grad + y.grad. I find x.grad has the same value as x.grad.data so that I think x.grad and x.grad.data are the same thing and there is a link between x.grad and x.grad.data, meaning we can get an attribute of an object via the name of an object. But I want to know how this link is realized in python. Would you like to give some hints?

Comment: Quite simply by implementing the `__add__` (and very obviously quite a few others) magic method, cf this _very__ naive example : https://gist.github.com/BrunoDesthuilliers/81cb6addc7aab626d66f3486a0189d90. FWIW pytorch is open source so you can check by yourself...

Answer (score 0):

Even in languages with distinct scalar and object types (like Java or C++), attributes can be objects (hopefully else OO wouldn't buy you much), so there's nothing wrong, unexpected or suprising in having an attribute that have methods.

When it comes to Python there's no scalar type and everything is an object (really everything, including modules, classes, methods and functions), it's hardly surprising that you found an attribute with a method.

Comment: Thank you for your nice answers. If x.grad is an object attribute, why can I get the value of x.grad via typing x.grad directly instead of x.grad.data? (I find that the value of x.grad is equal to the value of x.grad.data). Similar confusion occurs to me when using python numpy. For example. I define an array by x = np.array([1,2]), where x can be regarded as an instance of class array initialized with [1,2]. I think that I should get the value [1,2] by typing x.somthing. In fact, I can get [1,2] directly by typing x instead of x.something. This really confuses me.

Comment: Python has strong support for operator overloading and compostion/delegation,  so all this is quite easy to do really. You may want to read this https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names to get a first glance at what can be done...